# Dirac notation notation equality

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, notation, eigenvalue

I'm going trough my quantum mechanics notes but I don't understand why:

$$H|\phi_{m}\rangle\langle\phi_{n}|-|\phi_{m}\rangle\langle\phi_{n}|H=a_{m}\langle\phi_{n}|-a_{n}|\phi_{m}\rangle.$$

What is exactly the meaning of $a_{m}$ and $a_{n}$ and why this equality holds?

Comment: The quality of lecture notes varies wildly depending on the author. Some are excellent and some are outright harmful. I recommend strongly reading a proper textbook. Especially when it comes to the basics like Dirac notation. Universities normally provide a good selection of proper textbooks and finding one that suits you is more than worth the time. Reading a well structured text enables you to master the topics instead of fumbling through the curriculum.

Comment: Unless the subscripts $m$ and $n$ denote components, what sense does it make adding a ket and a bra? In my view, it's like adding a row vector to a column vector, which is not even defined.

Comment: As @jim mentioned in his answer, $\lvert \phi \rangle \langle \psi \rvert$ is an operator, and there is nothing unusual about adding operators together, as they form a vector space. What I mean is that in the RHS the first term is a ket and the second term is a bra. I don't think that we can add two different objects from different vector spaces, as a ket is a vector and a bra is a covector.

Comment: @tonetillo4 It would probably be helpful to get some feedback from OP about the context of the notes

Comment: @FernandoGarcía, yes definitely.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer should be $$ a_m | \phi_m \rangle\langle \phi_n | - a_n | \phi_m \rangle\langle \phi_n |.$$ There is nothing unusual in seeing objects like $| \phi_m \rangle\langle \phi_n |$ it is a projection like operator.

Taking H  to be the an hermitian operator with eigenstates $ |\phi_m \rangle $ and $ | \phi_n \rangle $, then the first term is straightforward, $ H | \phi_m \rangle \langle \phi_n | = a_m | \phi_m \rangle\langle \phi_n | $.

For the second term use $| \phi_m \rangle \langle \phi_n | H =  | \phi_m \rangle ( H | \phi_n \rangle )^\dagger $ and use for a hermitian operator the eigenvalues are real.

Comment: But what are exactly $a_{m}$ and $a_{n}$ ?

Comment: $ a_m, a_n $ are the he eigenvalues  of the operator $H$ corresponding to the eigenstates $ | \phi_m > \mbox{ and } | \phi_n>$., $ H | \phi_m > = a_m | \phi_m >, H | \phi_n > = a_n | \phi_n>$. There actual value depends on what the operator $ H $ is. usually $ H $ is taken to be the Hamiltonian of the system.

Comment: I don't think that $H$ can be an operator because then the inequality doesn't hold. I'm with @akhmeteli in that it has to be involved in some type of inner product.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a wild mix of notations. This equality probably holds only if $H$ is some state, rather than a Hamiltonian, but in that case, it should probably be denoted as a bra or ket vector ($\langle H|$ or $|H\rangle)$. Then one can imagine that $a_n=\langle\phi_n|H\rangle$, but even then, the equation only holds if, for some reason, $a_n$ are all real, rather than complex.